# "component un-defined" error in my use state Hook of React code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have code of React and I used usestate Hook my code was running well but I don't know why but an warning occur like "all child of list must have unique key" either I have put the unique in child of list where it required . anyhow my question is when I tried to fix this problem and I make some changes in my code then suddenly an error occur of
'setTodo' is not defined

```
 Line 34:5:   'setTodo' was used before it was defined      no-use-before-define
  Line 34:17:  'todos' was used before it was defined
```

which is defined in usestate hook .I am going to paste my code here please anyone can help to fix this I will bold the line where I have defined hook please have a look

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './MyComponents/Header.js';
import Todos from './MyComponents/Todos';
import Footer from './MyComponents/Footer';
import { AddTodo } from './MyComponents/AddTodo';
import React, { useState } from 'react';



function App() {
  const onDelete=(todo)=>{
    //console.log("here is delete",todo);
   //this way of deleting an array item is not working properly in react as it does not update my dom
  //   let index = todos.indexOf(todo);
  //    todos.splice(index);
    setTodo(todos.filter((e)=>{
      return e!==todo;
  }))
  }
  const addTodo=(title,desc)=>{
    console.log("Title and description is adding here",title,desc)
    let sno;
    if(sno==0){
      sno=1;
    }
    else{
      sno=todos[todos.length-1].sno+1
    const mytodo={
      sno: sno,
      title:title,
      desc: desc
    }
    console.log(mytodo)
    setTodo([...todos,mytodo])
    }
  //therefore i will use hook (state hook) to del array item in React
  let mytitle = "My-Todos-List"
**  const [todos, setTodo] = useState([
 **   {
      sno: 1,
      title: "Attock",
      description: "collection of taxes"
    },
    {
      sno: 2,
      title: "Jehlum",
      description: "Verification of taxes"
    },
    {
      sno: 3,
      title: "Sangjhani",
      description: "staff authentication"
    }
  ]);
  
  return (
    <div>
  <Header title1={mytitle} searchBar={true}/>
  <AddTodo addtodo={addTodo}/>
  <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete}/>
  <Footer/>
   </div>
  );

  }}
export default App;
```

I have searched but I got response to import react in this way "

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

but that is already imported with this script

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

I am expecting that please guide me where I am going wrong in defining (setTodo) and (todos)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the hook before its even defined. Move the hook to the top:

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './MyComponents/Header.js';
import Todos from './MyComponents/Todos';
import Footer from './MyComponents/Footer';
import { AddTodo } from './MyComponents/AddTodo';
import React, { useState } from 'react';



function App() {
const [todos, setTodo] = useState([
    {
      sno: 1,
      title: "Attock",
      description: "collection of taxes"
    },
    {
      sno: 2,
      title: "Jehlum",
      description: "Verification of taxes"
    },
    {
      sno: 3,
      title: "Sangjhani",
      description: "staff authentication"
    }
  ]);
  const onDelete=(todo)=>{
    //console.log("here is delete",todo);
   //this way of deleting an array item is not working properly in react as it does not update my dom
  //   let index = todos.indexOf(todo);
  //    todos.splice(index);
    setTodo(todos.filter((e)=>{
      return e!==todo;
  }))
  }
  const addTodo=(title,desc)=>{
    console.log("Title and description is adding here",title,desc)
    let sno;
    if(sno==0){
      sno=1;
    }
    else{
      sno=todos[todos.length-1].sno+1
    const mytodo={
      sno: sno,
      title:title,
      desc: desc
    }
    console.log(mytodo)
    setTodo([...todos,mytodo])
    }
  //therefore i will use hook (state hook) to del array item in React
  let mytitle = "My-Todos-List"
 
  
  return (
    <div>
  <Header title1={mytitle} searchBar={true}/>
  <AddTodo addtodo={addTodo}/>
  <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete}/>
  <Footer/>
   </div>
  );

  }}
export default App;
```

Your second issue with the key, you have defined a map/loop somewhere, which needs a unique key. Simply put a valid key inside your map like so:

pseudo code:

```
const items = [
 {
  id: 1,
  value: 'test'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  value: 'tree'
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  value: 'tom'
 },
]
    
items.map((item) => <div key={item.id}>{item.value}</div>)
```

Comment: yes that's great thanks for your precious time and suggestion, it's a lot for me. Yes sir I have put unique key in map but I have also used hr tag to make good in better looking when I remove that so now warning has fixed

Comment: @fahadkhurshid thank you - if it has resolved your issue, please upvote and put it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have written some comments in the code explaining to you why I did that changes in the code.

```
// I will prefer to order imports in this way. Starting from react and external libraries, then components and ending with css
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './MyComponents/Header.js';
import Todos from './MyComponents/Todos';
import Footer from './MyComponents/Footer';
import { AddTodo } from './MyComponents/AddTodo';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  // Move const and useState at the top of the component
  const mytitle = "My-Todos-List" //This should be a const is non-editable
  const [todos, setTodo] = useState(() => [ //here I use lazy initialization. I leave you a link below to read about it
   {
      sno: 1,
      title: "Attock",
      description: "collection of taxes"
    },
    {
      sno: 2,
      title: "Jehlum",
      description: "Verification of taxes"
    },
    {
      sno: 3,
      title: "Sangjhani",
      description: "staff authentication"
    }
  ]);

  // and then you can write your handlers that use `useState` todos and setTodo without warnings
  const onDelete=(todo)=>{
    setTodo(todos.filter((e)=>{
      return e!==todo;
  }))
  }
  const addTodo=(title,desc)=>{
    let sno;
    if(sno==0){
      sno=1;
    }
    else{
      sno=todos[todos.length-1].sno+1
    const mytodo={
      sno: sno,
      title:title,
      desc: desc
    }
    setTodo([...todos,mytodo])
    }
  
  return (
    <div>
  <Header title1={mytitle} searchBar={true}/>
  <AddTodo addtodo={addTodo}/>
  <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete}/>
  <Footer/>
   </div>
  );

  }}
export default App;
```

Read more about lazy initialization https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates

Comment: yes that's great thanks for your presious time and suggestion , now it work I have one more issue that I am facing in the form of warning that

Comment: yes that's great thanks for your precious time and suggestion, it's a lot for me

Comment: Thank you, hope you can improve your code and learn with it. If it has helped you please vote up and accept the answer! And if I can help you with something else let me know